# Word order: Tucker Carlson’s Exit Shows Who’s the Real Star at Fox

Tags: word-order

I saw this headline at the Politico web site: "Tucker Carlson’s Exit Shows Who’s the Real Star at Fox". Shouldn't it be "Tucker Carlson’s Exit Shows **Who** the Real Star at Fox **Is**"?

I thought that since the second part of the sentence wasn't a question, the verb (is) should come after the subject (who). Does this rule no longer hold? And when did it disappear?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147029/discussion-on-question-by-eltomito-word-order-tucker-carlsons-exit-shows-whos); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

In an embedded interrogative clause, the subject-auxiliary inversion does not occur:

> (1) *It questions whether **he is** the real star at Fox.*
> (2) ??*It questions whether **is he** the real star at Fox.* 
> (3) *It shows **who is** the real star at Fox.*
> (4) *It shows who **the real star is** at Fox.*
> (5) *It shows who **the real star at Fox is**.*

In order for (3)-(5) to work, therefore, the subjects of the embedded clauses should be ***who***, ***the real star***, ***the real star at Fox***, respectively.

This is why you can't say (6) or (7):

> (6) ??*It shows where **is the real star at Fox**.* 
> (7) ??*It shows **who are** you.*

In the Politico title, the writer simply treated *who* as the subject of the embedded clause, as in (3), which he certainly can.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147030/discussion-on-answer-by-jk2-word-order-tucker-carlsons-exit-shows-whos-the-re); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one alternative explanation beyond grammatical correctness:
The economics of online publishing.

The proposed revision adds one word and a single character.

[image]